# Queue TFS2015 XAML based build and pass on parameter using REST API

Tags: xaml, tfs, tfs-2015

I am trying to start a build from Powershell using the TFS 2015 REST API. I am sucessful in starting a new build using REST API after following the [Post](http://blog.nwcadence.com/vststfs-rest-api-the-basics-and-working-with-builds-and-releases/).

Now i am trying to pass some custom parameter that appears in the Build def parameter through the REST API.
I am not sure whether it can be done, if anyone has any previous knowledge please help.

I am using TFS 2015 and XAML based build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an optional option with REST API for querying build called **parameters** :*Parameters to pass to the build. This is optional. If not specified, the default variables for the definition will be used.*

**Example:**

```
"parameters": "{\"system.debug\":\"true\",\"BuildConfiguration\":\"debug\",\"BuildPlatform\":\"x64\"}"
```

More details please refer the document from MSDN: [Builds](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds)

Comment: Does not seem to work when the build we are trying to queue is a Xaml build and not TFS build

Comment: @HamidShahid Thanks, my omissions. Seems not all  parameters  could work  when use Rest API to request a XAML build passing the parameters. If you are going to use such as msbuild arguments, you may have to use the workaround either through tfsbuild command line  or TFS SDK, details please seem my answer in your new created case.